# how to get all active session_id of a user ??

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using SSO mechanishm.when user gets logged out from sso portal then want to close all active sessions of dat user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rails supports this. Maybe you have to record the relationship between user id and session id by yourself, e.g. create a model/table and save the relationship on logging in.

Comment: thx a ton Yanhao, even i found no way to do that, i think making user_sessions table as u mentioned will work for sure.